# Inserting strings into an AVL tree in C++?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, avl-tree

I understand how an AVL tree works with integers.. but I'm having a hard time figuring out a way to insert strings into one instead. How would the strings be compared?

I've thought of just using the ASCII total value and sorting that way.. but in that situation, inserting two identical ASCII words (such as "tied" and "diet") would seem to return an error.

How do you get around this? Am I thinking about it in the wrong way, and need a different way to sort the nodes?

And no they don't need to be alphabetical or anything... just in an AVL tree so I can search for them quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with strings, you normally use a lexical comparison -- i.e., you start with the first character of each string. If one is less than the other (e.g., with "diet" vs. "tied", "d" is less than "t") the comparison is based on that letter. If and only if the first letters are equal, you go to the second letter, and so on. The two are equal only if every character (in order) from beginning to end of the strings are equal.

Comment: `int string::compare(const string&) const` is a lexical comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since an AVL tree is an ordered structure, the [`int string::compare(const string&) const`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) routine should be able to give you an indication of how to order the strings.

If order of the items is actually irrelevant, you'll get better performance out of an unordered structure that can take better advantage of what you're trying to do: a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

The mapping of something like a string to a fixed-size key is called a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), and the phenomenon where multiple keys are mapped to the same value is called a [collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29).  Collisions are expected to happen occasionally when hashing, and a basic data structure would needs to be extended to handle it, perhaps by making each node a "bucket" (linked list, vector, array, what have you) of all the items that have colliding hash values that is then searched linearly.

Comment: Hash table won't necessarily be faster than a tree. It all depends on its size (and of course assuming hash function is ok). I mean, when you have no preliminary information about the string count from the beginning - AVL tree is not a bad alternative

Comment: `compare` is an old C-like method. `std::string` naturally supports `operator<`, which is much easier to apprehend in my experience.

Comment: @valdo Agreed; I like AVL trees personally but only with ordered keys, though I find red-black trees more commonly implemented in practice.  If order doesn't matter, hash tables give you more space/speed tradeoff flexibility, and they can be resized if they get too slow due to high fill/large buckets.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It's kind of old-school but it allows you to make sure you loop over the string contents only once and yet separately handle the three cases of less than, equal, and greater than.  With the overloaded operators, you potentially need to try both `operator <` and `operator ==` to distinguish the three cases.

Comment: @JeffreyHantin: well, you can make do with `<` only because of the anti-symmetry property, but it does require two calls instead of one yes. On the other hand `if (s.compare(s2) == 0)` just feels weird, I wish they had used a proper enum for the result. Compare it to `if (cmp(s, s2) == EQ)`, does not it read better ?